# Do I need a transit visa for Kuwait to recheck in my baggage?

Tags: visas, transit, luggage, german-citizens, kuwait

I am a German citizen flying to Kathmandu in November. I have a layover in Kuwait for 4 hours. I will need to recheck-in my luggage.

I will leave the international zone to recheck-in my baggage? Do I need a transit visa?

Also, what do I need to do to get the transit visa? I got the information that I will need a visa for the next country I will travel to. But in Kathmandu I would get the visa on arrival.

Does anyone have experience with the transit visa?

Answer (score 12):

Since you need to collect your luggage and check in again, you'll have to go through immigration. [According to Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=KW&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=00&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C), German citizens do need visas to enter Kuwait. The same source also says that you are eligible for a visa on arrival, for a fee of "no more than KWD 3" (€9).

If you want to save time while transiting, you could also get an e-visa in advance. German citizens [are eligible.](https://evisa.moi.gov.kw/evisa/home_e.do) You can apply using [this website](https://evisa.moi.gov.kw/evisa/home_e.do).